# "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" error while installing Wine in Ubuntu 12.1

Tags: package-management, software-installation, wine

I can't install Wine on Ubuntu 12.1.  It worked in previous versions, but with 12.1 I get a bunch of errors.

When installing Q4 Wine from the Ubuntu Software Center, I get:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

I've read on the forums that there is a problem with installing a 32-bit application on a 64-bit machine (mine is 64), so I tried:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

But this fails because it reports that these are invalid options with `dpkg`.  It did seem to work for others with similar Wine installation problems, but not me.

I've also tried installing Wine from the terminal, but no luck there either.

Comment: Please, edit your question to include the output of `sudo apt-get install wine`?

Comment: 12.1? what do you mean, first version of '12 i.e. 12.04 or 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Wine in Ubuntu Software Center (official repos) is old and not well maintained.  Install the [Ubuntu Wine PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa) and try again:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge wine

 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
 sudo apt-get update

 # resolve held pack packages that might be dependencies
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 

 sudo apt-get install wine
```